# Why do differ %M and %F in Log4perl PatternLayout in special cases?

Tags: perl, log4perl

*The original question has been reformulated, to be clear for later use*

I find the following issue to be weird. In some cases %M and %F refers to different files. For example int the following case:

**Foo.pm** contains

```
use warnings;
sub x { 2; 1; }
1;
```

**test.pl** contains

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Log::Log4perl qw/:easy/;
Log::Log4perl->easy_init({ file => 'STDOUT', layout => '[%p{1}] %m{chomp} [%l]%n' });
$::log = Log::Log4perl->get_logger;
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    local $Log::Log4perl::caller_depth = $Log::Log4perl::caller_depth + 1;
    $::log->warn(shift);
};
require "Foo.pm";
```

Result is:

```
[W] Useless use of a constant in void context at Foo.pm line 2. [main:: Foo.pm (2)]
```

So file is "*Foo.pm*", but the function is "*main::*".

I found that the weird behavior is in connection with errors/warnings happening in compile time of "require".

Why do %M and %F differ?

Thanks, FERcsI

Comment: Just a small extension: Actually $SIG{__WARN__} uses $log->warn and $SIG{__DIE__} uses $log->error, but there art no more differences...

Comment: Perl version I use is 5.16...

Answer (score 0):

```
    %F File where the logging event occurred
    %M Method or function where the logging request was issued
```

Comment: Thanks. I've read the POD, just this does not explain the difference between a "warn" and an "error"...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer to my own question through some experiments.

PatternLayout uses "*caller*" entries for file name (and line no, etc.). However, method names are a bit more complicated. In a usual case method name is also available in the next level of "caller" (the same level contains an *ANON*). However, in some special cases of eval (e.g. request) multiple level search in "*caller*" has to be done.

In addition, request does not “have” a subroutine in the imported file, so %M returns the function including the request, but the file name and line no values refer to the included file.

As a side effect, you are not able to use request's caller level: request's line number is unreachable for any level of "caller_depth" (as opposed to “*caller*”)...